# Should I say "Ameen" loudly if I'm the only one to do so?

Tags: salat, muslim-practices, masjid, madhhab

In a congregation where the "Ameen" is said silently after the Fatiha such as the Hanafi, if I'm of the view that the stronger view is it should be say loudly or my particular school of thought believes so, then is it best to say it even though I would be the only one and be the "odd one out"?

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu Alaikum,
Yes, even if you are alone, you can say Ameen loudly. Because the word "Ameen" is like asking Allah to answer your du'a (From the recitation of Fatiha)

Comment: Would it be possible to quote a scholar who shares this view?